# Sum While melting columns in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to melt 2 columns and take there sums as value . For example

```
df <- data.frame(A = c("x", "y", "z"), B = c(1, 2, 3), Cat1 = c(1, 4, 3), New2 = c(4, 4, 4))
```

Expected output

```
New_Col  Sum
Cat1      8
New2      12
```

Answer (score 2):

Or using `base R` with `colSums` after selecting the columns of interest and then convert the named vector to data.frame with `stack`

```
stack(colSums(df[c("Cat1", "New2")]))[2:1]
   ind values
1 Cat1      8
2 New2     12
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course

```r
df %>% 
    summarise(across(starts_with('Cat'), sum)) %>% 
    pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = 'New_Col', values_to = 'Sum')
```

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  New_Col   Sum
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 Cat1        8
2 Cat2       12
```

Comment: Say, the columns are different. I have edited my question

Comment: Well, you need some way to indicate which columns you want to summarise across. In case these are columns with indices 3, 4, you could substitute `starts_with()` with `3:4`